# remains an integral part of its menu that it has expanded an option

Tags: error

Does the following sentence from CNN miss something to make it grammatical?
Should "such" have been inserted between "remains" and "an"?

> The sandwich remains an integral part of its menu that it has expanded an option to include a plant-based version.

https://edition.cnn.com/2021/12/02/business/burger-king-whopper-original-price/index.html

Comment: Yes, this is a simple editing mistake, and it should read, "*...remains such an...*"

Comment: @gotube Doe "expanded an option to include a plant-based version" make sense?

Comment: No, you cannot "expand an option". You can expand a menu by adding options. CNN is really getting torn apart on on ELL this week.

Comment: How about this revision "The sandwich remains such an integral part of its menu that it has expanded to include a plant-based version"?

Comment: That sounds like the sandwich expanded. "*...that they have expanded it to...*" works

Comment: If so, should "its menu" be changed to "their menu"?